# Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob v11.1.7 throws exception while creating Queueclient

Tags: azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage-queues

While using "Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob" Version="11.1.7"

```
 var queue = storageAccount.CreateCloudQueueClient()
                .GetQueueReference(QueueName);
```

Above line of code throws below exception
*"message": "Method 'get_NetworkTimeout' in type 'Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Queue.QueueRequestOptions' from assembly 'Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Queue, Version=11.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' does not have an implementation.",*

if you replace "Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob" Version="11.1.7" with Version="11.1.1" **no exception & working as expected**. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the version of the `Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Queue` you used is `11.1.1`. I used the `Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob` Version=`11.1.7` and `Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Queue` Version=`11.1.1` which can reproduce your problem.

So the root cause is that `Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob` Version=`11.1.7` and `Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Queue` Version=`11.1.1` seem to conflict with each other.

Solution:
You can use `Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob` Version=`11.1.7` and `Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Queue` Version=`11.1.7`, or `Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob` Version=`11.1.1` and `Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Queue` Version=`11.1.1`, then you will solve this problem.